# There is anyway to view package version list in PBO org

Tags: package-version

I was created a lot of package version and sometime want to check out current usage and how many was created, there is any way to view it via UI instead do `sf package version list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you must access this data through the CLI. It would be theoretically possible to build a custom UI, e.g. through a Heroku app, but there is no native UI that lists packages and their versions.

Comment: ohmm okay thank you